# Find W/Glide: Failed to find GeneratedAppGlideModule

Tags: android, kotlin

when i run the application i got this error

W/Glide: Failed to find GeneratedAppGlideModule. You should include an annotationProcessor compile dependency on com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler in your application and a @GlideModule annotated AppGlideModule implementation or LibraryGlideModules will be silently ignored

however this error related to display the image on recycle view however i used glide in another part of the app and the image is displayed well.

this is the row layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_180sdp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_90sdp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_10sdp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    android:elevation="@dimen/_3sdp"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_popular_meal_item"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"></ImageView>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

this is the RecyclerView

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rec_view_meals_popular"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_90sdp"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_25sdp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_10sdp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_over_popular_items"/>
```

this is my AdapterClass

```
class MostPopularAdapter(): RecyclerView.Adapter<MostPopularAdapter.PopularMealViewHolder>() {

    private var mealsList = ArrayList<CategoryMeal>()

    fun setMeal(mealsList:ArrayList<CategoryMeal>) {
        this.mealsList=mealsList
        //when we set the new List , refresh the adapter to update the view
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }



    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): PopularMealViewHolder {
       return PopularMealViewHolder(PopularItemsRowLayoutBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),parent,false))
    }


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PopularMealViewHolder, position: Int) {

       Glide.with(holder.itemView)
           .load(mealsList[position].strMealThumb)
           .into(holder.binding.imgPopularMealItem)
    }


    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return mealsList.size
    }


    inner class PopularMealViewHolder( var binding: PopularItemsRowLayoutBinding):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)
}
```

//HomeFragment

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    lateinit var binding: FragmentHomeBinding
    lateinit var homeViewModel:HomeViewModel
    lateinit var randomMeal: Meal
    lateinit var popularItemAdapter: MostPopularAdapter
    var mealsList = ArrayList<CategoryMeal>()

   
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val repository = Repository()
        val homeViewModelFactory = HomeViewModelFactory(repository)
        homeViewModel=ViewModelProvider(this,homeViewModelFactory).get(HomeViewModel::class.java)

        popularItemAdapter= MostPopularAdapter()


    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        binding= FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false)
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return binding.root

    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        preparePopularItemsRecyclerView()
      
        observePopularItems()


    }


    fun observePopularItems(){
        homeViewModel.getPopularItems("Seafood")
        homeViewModel.result.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            popularItemAdapter.setMeal(mealsList)
        })
    }


    // setup RecyclerView
    fun preparePopularItemsRecyclerView(){
        binding.recViewMealsPopular.apply {
            // set the layoutManager
            layoutManager=LinearLayoutManager(activity,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false)
            adapter=popularItemAdapter
        }
    }





}
```

i tried the below solution but not work as when i try to use GlideAppModule insted of Glide , the complier canot find the with() like that GlideAppModule.with(...)

```
import com.bumptech.glide.annotation.GlideModule
import com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule

@GlideModule
class GlideAppModule: AppGlideModule()
```

Comment: I got the same error and I'm looking for its solution

Comment: The issue was not related to the glide it was a mistake in the data I observe it.so note that maybe your issue also not related to the glide itself

Comment: can u explain a little bit? thank you!